# Access to Notes & Attachments for users on a different account

Tags: profile, sharing, roles, notes

I would like to give access to attachments on one account to users on a different account. The users have Customer Community User profile, as far as I have tried manual sharing isn't possible.

Is there a way to provide access to Notes & Attachments on different account? Could someone please explain?

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered a similar requirement and could not resolve it by using standard profiles customization and what I did to overcome is created 1 custom object who have parent as account then created notes and attachment below that custom object now you have cross access between the accounts to see notes and attachments

Comment: Will that work when account sharing is private?

Comment: If you are using look up relation between account and custom object